# how to hide or disable actionMode in CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-dialogfragment

I want to show a `ListView` in an `AlertDialog`.
When in multiple choice mode, the action mode displays.

I don't need it, can I hide it or something?

[image](http://static.flickr.com/8772/17096949448_eed23df998_o.png)

I try to `return false` in my `MultiChoiceModeListener.onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)`

but it can't show multiple choices anymore.

Comment: Link to images instead of embedding them and someone else can edit them in.

Comment: You can use `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE`

Comment: @Piyush this doesnt allows to multiselect content .